# Проблема при загрузке изображения с CDN: файл приходит меньшего размера чем должен

Tags: c#, wpf, cdn

Есть изображение: `https://media.alienwarearena.com/images/content/rank-insignias/lg/10.png`
Пытаюсь его вывести с помощью `<Image/>` (`<Image Source="адрес">`), получаю в итоге пустое окно.

Думаю, ну хорошо, попробую скачать его, пишу:

```
var imgUrl = new Uri("https://media.alienwarearena.com/images/content/rank-insignias/lg/10.png");
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(imgUrl, "10.png");
```

Результатом получаю битое изображение, которое весит 14кб (28кб оригинал).
Пытался добавлять разные заголовки (все, что на изображение снизу), да что то толку нет.

Запрос через обычный браузер:

[image: Headers]

Может кто знает, что мешает работе с этим адресом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы скачиваете картинку с адреса `http://`, а нужно скачивать по `https://`.

Проблема здесь в том что `DownloadFile` [по умолчанию не делает повторные запросы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039113/93540) если ему дан код ответа 301, что именно и происходит в данном случае при попытке скачать картинку по простому HTTP.

```
$ curl -I http://media.alienwarearena.com/...
HTTP/1.1 301 Force SSL
```

Другая проблема может быть в особенностях CDN, которая, похоже, всегда отдает сжатые файлы. Например, если попросить cURL ждать сжатый ответ, то все скачивается без ошибок:

```
curl 'https://media.alienwarearena.com/images/content/rank-insignias/lg/10.png' --compressed -o 10.png
```

Comment: Ох, извините. Это уже мои попытки скачать изображение (пробовал и `http` и `https`, результат тот же.). Исправил в вопросе.

Comment: Забавно, даже `curl` показывает вес в 14кб и если написать `curl https://media.alienwarearena.com/images/content/rank-insignias/lg/10.png --output test.png`, то файл `test.png` будет битый. Любопытно, в чем же дело...

Comment: Посмотрите, там обязательное сжатие

Comment: Хм, а вот это то, что надо. Спасибо вам большое!