# Не загружаются изображения Xamarin: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

При попытке отобразить изображение

```
<Image Source="https://i1.wp.com/doumer.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/cropped-Cool-Coders-Logo-6.png" />
```

возникает ошибка:

> Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid.

Долго искал решение и наткнулся на такой вариант: [Resolve Image Loading Error in Xamarin Forms](https://doumer.me/resolve-image-loading-error-in-xamarin-forms), 
[ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1869)
но он не помог мне.
Если кто знает в чем может быть проблема помогите.

Comment: Со всеми изображениями так? Дайте наверно полную ссылку, может с ней проблемы ([сжатие например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002709/220553))?

Comment: Если в вопросе действительно ссылка, по который берется изображение, то не удивительно, что не грузится - ссылка неполная.

Comment: Ссылка была полная. Ее где то урезало. Дело не в ссылке. Пробовал разные изображения грузить с разных источников. Одно и тоже. Так же пробовал локально с проекта, так все работает. Проблема в том что приложение не грузит изображение.

Comment: Выяснил еще один момент. Под iOS все работает. Проблема в Android или в EmulatorAndroid.

Answer (score 0):

Это было исправлено в Xamarin.Form 4.2.0.815419.