# Файл скачивается не полностью c#

Tags: c#

Такая проблема. Я скачиваю файл с ФТП через обычный WebClient()

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("link"), path);
```

В итоге файл скачивается, прогресс бар отображает информацию правильно, но когда файл скачается до конца и вызовется данная функция:

```
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                ;
            }
            else
            {
                g.Dispose();
                label1.Text = "Распаковка игровых ресурсов, ожидайте...";

                (new Thread(delegate ()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathToGame + @"\RealRussia.zip", pathToGame + @"\");
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToGame + @"\RealRussia.zip"))
                            System.IO.File.Delete(pathToGame + @"\RealRussia.zip");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        showUserNotice(ex.Message);
                    }
                })).Start();

                downloadStartedNow = false;
            }
        };
```

То ничего не происходит, а когда перейду по пути path (куда должен скачаться архив), то при открытии его получаю: неожиданный конец архива

> Скачанный архив весит 4.1 вместо 4.2 гб, но если скачиваю архив самостоятельно с ФТП, то всё весит как надо и открывается как надо, также разпаковывается как надо, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А вы проверяли работу своего кода на каком-нибудь более легком файле, скажем, на пару сотен мегабайт?

Comment: Проверял. На обычных файлах всё отлично работает (они докачиваются полностью), а вот с архивами беда, что может быть не так?

Comment: Очень похоже на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002709/220553) случай. Ну а так, я вам советую отказаться вовсе от `WebClient`, ибо он уже давно является устаревшим.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452284/7482894

Comment: Bulson, попробовал этот способ, скачивается также повреждённый архив.

Comment: Может у вас какой прокси в сети используется?

Comment: У меня лежит на веб-хостинге, на фтп, сборка. Я просто подключаюсь к этому фтп и качаю архив.

Comment: Вы можете нам предоставить ссылку на файл, который требуется скачать? Мне кажется так будет проще.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GSH6Gas3yhkFCxlnryhwKESqCvJQIw9m/view | а так, скачиваю его с ФТП.

Comment: И как вы предлагаете нам тестировать ваш сервер, давая нам ссылку на гугл?

Comment: А мне данные от фтп давать сюда? Можем пойти в вк или дискорд, или скайп?

Comment: А вы данные FTP решили давать своим клиентам? Вот мы ваши клиенты сейчас, хотим опробовать ваш софт. Как быть? Логины и пароли давать нам не в коем случае не надо, в другие соц. сети мы тоже не пойдем.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, вообщем я особо не понял что я должен скинуть, но скину функцию которая вообще  скачивает файл.
https://imgur.com/LJFp1Kd

Comment: И что в ней может быть не так? (Файл скачивается не до конца, хотя прогресс доходит до 100 процентов, все 4103372800 из 4103372800 скачиваются по тестам, но на деле там 401.....)

Comment: Если вашим приложением будут пользоваться люди, то не удивляйтесь потом, что вас взломали. C# весьма открытый язык и собранное приложение довольно просто открывается (а там и ваш логин и пароль в коде). Советую сделать для приложения анонимный доступ. По поводу вашего вопроса: У вас проблема не в коде, а в сервере. Он у вас либо сжимает файл для отправки, либо имеет еще чего. Если взять ваш код, добавить в пустой проект и указать рабочий сервер FTP. то все отработает (ибо сервер не просит ничего лишнего). Чего просит ваш сервер, выясняйте сами, вы нам его не даете, нам его не проверить.

Comment: @waparabka Уточните с точностью до байтов: сколько изначально весит файл на фтп сервере и сколько скачивается через вашу программу. Если скачивается больше чем на сервере, то скорее всего качаете в ASCII режиме, а не в binary.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `request.UseBinary = true;`